# List não adiciona, apenas atualiza os itens. ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Boa tarde,

Sou novo na área e estou tendo um pequeno problema ao criar uma solução simples com ASP.Net MVC, usando .Net 7. Basicamente é um sistema para validação de planilhas excel, que caso estejam corretas, faz a compactação dessas planilhas em um arquivo .zip e dispara para um e-mail. O que acontece é o seguinte: Estou tentando adicionar as planilhas em uma lista que criei na Model, para que após isso seja realizado a compactação dos arquivos, porém, ao invés de adicionar mais itens a lista, ela apenas atualiza com a planilha recém validada. Poderiam me ajudar?

Segue código:

Função POST de validação do Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ValidarPlanilha(IFormFile arquivo, string tipoPlanilha)
        {
            try
            {
                if (arquivo == null || arquivo.Length == 0)
                  {

                    return BadRequest("Por favor, selecione um arquivo.");
                  }

                Workbook workbook = new Workbook(arquivo.OpenReadStream());
                Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];


                string mensagem;

                switch (tipoPlanilha)
                {

                    case ("Clientes"):

                        mensagem = _planilhaService.ValidarPlanilha(worksheet);
                        model.MensagemValidacao = mensagem;
                        if (mensagem == "Planilha OK!")
                        {

                            model.ArquivosTemporarios.Add(arquivo);
                            return Json(new { mensagemValidacao = model.MensagemValidacao });


                        }

                        return Json(new { mensagemValidacao = model.MensagemValidacao });


                    default:

                        return BadRequest("Valor Inválido");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Ocorreu um erro ao processar a planilha: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Tentei armazenar a informação em Cache para persistência dos dados, e também usar o Session State, porém, nenhuma das opções funcionou de fato. Acredito que seja um erro de principiante, mas infelizmente não consigo localizar um caminho para seguir. Todo o processo de validação funciona normalmente, o único problema é essa questão da lista mesmo. Se necessário alguma outra parte do código para melhor análise é só avisar!

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia/Boa tarde/Boa noite!

Depois de umas boas horas de sono perdida e extensos momentos de lamentação, resolvi o problema que vinha enfrentando. De uma forma "simples". Refiz a função POST do controller para executar as duas ações em sequência, para que a informação da lista não fosse perdida em meio as requisições HTTP. Ou seja, tanto o envio da lista do JavaScript ao controller, quanto o disparo do e-mail eram feitas em cadeia na mesma função, dessa forma solucionando meu problema. Segue abaixo respectivos funções do [HttpPost] e JavaScript.

```
´´´
    [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult EnviarArquivosEEmail(List<IFormFile> arquivos)
            {
                // Adicione os arquivos recebidos à propriedade "Arquivos" do objeto model
                model.Arquivos.AddRange(arquivos);
                Console.WriteLine(model.Arquivos.Count);
                // Enviar e-mails com os anexos usando o serviço
                _planilhaService.EnviarEmailComAnexosAoFinal(model.Arquivos);
    
                // Retorne uma resposta indicando que os arquivos foram processados com sucesso
                return Ok();
            }
´´´

´´´
function enviarArquivosEEmailParaController() {
    // Exibir o alerta com as opções "Sim" ou "Cancelar"
    const confirmacao = window.confirm("As únicas planilhas enviadas serão as que o retorno foi positivo, deseja enviá-las?");

    // Se o usuário clicar em "Sim", prosseguir com o envio de arquivos e e-mails
    if (confirmacao) {
        // Crie um objeto FormData
        const formData = new FormData();

        // Adicione os arquivos da pilhaTemporaria ao FormData
        pilhaTemporaria.forEach((arquivo) => {
            formData.append("arquivos", arquivo.arquivo);
        });

        // Faça a requisição HTTP para a ação "EnviarArquivosEEmail"
        fetch("/Home/EnviarArquivosEEmail", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    // Arquivos enviados com sucesso, mostrar uma mensagem de sucesso
                    alert("Arquivos enviados com sucesso, obrigado!");
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    // Se houver um erro ao enviar os arquivos, exibir uma mensagem de erro
                    alert("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar os arquivos.");
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("Erro ao enviar os arquivos:", error);
                alert("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar os arquivos.");
            });
    }
    // Se o usuário clicar em "Cancelar" ou não confirmar, não fazer nada
}
´´´
```

Deixo o relato para caso mais alguém encontre o mesmo problema que eu! Até a próxima!